# Multithreading: Understanding semaphore behaviour

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, deadlock, semaphore

I am trying to get familiar with the concept of semaphores. For that reason I have written a simple semaphore class called `MySemaphore` and a Test-Class `MutexThread` utilizing said semaphore for *mutual exclusion*. Please find the code for my classes at the bottom of this post.

In my `MutexThread`-class I am using two `synchronized(mutex)` blocks in order to make sure that `acquire()` and the `release()` are both executed synchronized with my output to `stdout`. The result I get is as expected:

```
BORN -> Thread-0 born!
ACQUIRE -> Thread-0 is entering critical section!
BORN -> Thread-1 born!
BORN -> Thread-2 born!
BORN -> Thread-3 born!
BORN -> Thread-4 born!
BORN -> Thread-5 born!
BORN -> Thread-6 born!
BORN -> Thread-7 born!
BORN -> Thread-8 born!
BORN -> Thread-9 born!
RELEASE -> Thread-0 is leaving critical section!
INFO -> Thread-0 holdsLock: false
ACQUIRE -> Thread-1 is entering critical section!
RELEASE -> Thread-1 is leaving critical section!
INFO -> Thread-1 holdsLock: false
ACQUIRE -> Thread-2 is entering critical section!
RELEASE -> Thread-2 is leaving critical section!
INFO -> Thread-2 holdsLock: false
[...]
```

However, there are two things that I do not understand:

a) If I comment out the line `System.out.println("INFO -> " + getName() + " holdsLock: " + holdsLock(mutex));` at the end of the `while`-loop the JVM does no longer cycle through the independet threads. The output now looks like this:

```
BORN -> Thread-0 born!
ACQUIRE -> Thread-0 is entering critical section!
BORN -> Thread-1 born!
BORN -> Thread-2 born!
[...]
BORN -> Thread-9 born!
RELEASE -> Thread-0 is leaving critical section!
ACQUIRE -> Thread-0 is entering critical section!
RELEASE -> Thread-0 is leaving critical section!
ACQUIRE -> Thread-0 is entering critical section!
[...]
```

Why is this? Why does only `Thread-0` lock and unlock the `MySemaphore`-object? This is also true when I set `MAX_PARALLEL_THREADS` to an arbitrary `N`: In that case the JVM will always cycle through the same `N` threads, but other threads created never get access to the object. How can a single line of code (which just outputs some info to `stdout`) have such a huge impact?

b) When I use a semaphore-object from the class `Semaphore` from `java.util.concurrent` instead of my own `MySemaphore`-class the code does no longer work. It will lock up somewhere between the two `synchronized(mutex)`-blocks. The output looks like this:

```
BORN -> Thread-0 born!
ACQUIRE -> Thread-0 is entering critical section!
BORN -> Thread-1 born!
BORN -> Thread-2 born!
[...]
BORN -> Thread-9 born!
[... That's it. Program locks!]
```

Why is this? How is the class `Semaphore` from `java.util.concurrent` different than my own class? How does this result in the lock-up?

Code for my Semaphore-Class:

```
public class MySemaphore
{
    private int value;

    public MySemaphore(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public synchronized void acquire()
    {
        while(value <= 0)
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        }

        value--;
    }

    public synchronized void release()
    {
        value++;
        notify();
    }
}
```

Code for my Test-Class:

```
public class MutexThread extends Thread
{
    private MySemaphore mutex;

    public MutexThread(MySemaphore semaphore)
    {
        this.mutex = semaphore;
        start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                synchronized (mutex)
                {
                    mutex.acquire();
                    System.out.println("ACQUIRE -> " + getName() + " is entering critical section!");
                }

                sleep(1000);

                synchronized (mutex)
                {
                    mutex.release();
                    System.out.println("RELEASE -> " + getName() + " is leaving critical section!");
                }

                System.out.println("INFO -> " + getName() + " holdsLock: " + holdsLock(mutex));
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int THREADS = 10;
        final int MAX_PARALLEL_THREADS = 1;

        MySemaphore mutex = new MySemaphore(MAX_PARALLEL_THREADS);
        Thread[] t = new Thread[THREADS];

        for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++)
        {
            t[i] = new MutexThread(mutex);
            System.out.println("BORN -> " + t[i].getName() + " born!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did this question just get -1? What is unclear about it?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I updvoted it right now, as I think, your question is well stated and also contains compilable and runnable code. Trying to answer now ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `System.out.println(...)` is an IO operation. IO operations are basically very slow and usually also include blocking the current thread until the IO operation has finished.

If a thread is blocked due to an IO operation, this is the chance for other waiting threads to get processor time again and run. And this is exactly the behavior you see, when having the IO operation in the code.

When removing that IO operation from the code, the current thread directly continues to `acquire` the mutex. There is only a very small time window, where this thread could get blocked by the system, so another thread gets running. But ... this time window and thus this little chance exists.

Additionally, you are notifying only one thread in the `release` method. Chances are better, if you notify all waiting threads, so the system has more choices. Do it this way:

```
public synchronized void release() {
    value++;
    notifyAll();
}
```

Run your program now for a while. I did get some changes in the running threads.

Answer (score 2):

You use `synchronized (mutex)` both inside and outside the MySemaphore class. This always smells bad, and when you use java.util.concurrent.Semaphore instead of MySemaphore it causes a deadlock: the thread trying to release a semaphore is blocked on `synchronized (mutex)` which is owned by another thread which tries to aquire the semaphore.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have an alternative idea on how to implement a solution that leads to a synchronized `release` and I0-sequence without double-locking the object?

Comment: you need not to synchronize release and I0-sequence because they do not have common data. Just call println() before release().

Comment: You are totally right. However, I'd appreciate a solution that is independent from code order: If you have just one thread using the semaphore, you're idea works perfect, but if you have -say- 3 threads using the semaphore at the same time the output-release-order might become messed up do to the OS switching between threads, right?

Comment: `println("release")` and `println("aquire")` are synchronized naturally by companion semaphore operations. Two parallel `println("release")` can be swapped, but does it matter?

Comment: If they belong to different threads, then yes!? Let's say `Thread-A` prints "Thread-A: release", then the system switches to `Thread-B`, prints "Thread-B: release", actually releases `Thread-B`, then returns to `Thread-A` and finally releases `Thread-A`. In that scenario the programme reports that `Thread-A` released before `Thread-B` did, however that is not true!

Comment: yes I said that, and I see no harm. The threads make release in parallel, sometimes Thread A does it first, sometimes B. The log just reflects another possible scenario.